# printing of word document through excel

Tags: excel, printing, mailmerge, vba

I setup mail merge through vba code that input data into MS word file using excel. I would like to add print option from excel to attached printer. suppose there are 5 letters which needs to be print I want that when One letter is printed then the 2nd letter command will be given after 5 seconds and on.

Want to give print directly from excel (not from word) and to specific printer only like HP1100 etc etc.

any suggestion?

here is the code

```
   Sub CreateWordDocuments()
Dim CustRow, CustCol, LastRow, TemplRow, FrDays, ToDays As Long
Dim DocLoc, TagName, TagValue, TemplName, FileName, PrintStatus As String
Dim CurDt, LastAppDt As Date
Dim WordDoc, WordApp, OutApp, OutMail As Object
Dim WordContent As Word.Range
With Sheet1

  If .Range("B3").Value = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Please select a correct template from the drop down list"
    .Range("g3").Select
    Exit Sub
  End If
    TemplRow = .Range("B3").Value 'Set Template Row
    TemplName = .Range("G3").Value 'Set Template Name
    'FrDays = .Range("L3").Value 'Set From Days
    'ToDays = .Range("N3").Value 'Set To Days
    DocLoc = Sheet2.Range("F" & TemplRow).Value 'Word Document Filename

    'Open Word Template
    On Error Resume Next 'If Word is already running
    Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'Launch a new instance of Word
    Err.Clear
    'On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True 'Make the application visible to the user
    End If


    LastRow = .Range("c400").End(xlUp).Row  'Determine Last Row in Table
        For CustRow = 8 To LastRow
                PrintStatus = .Range("d" & CustRow).Value


                If PrintStatus = "Ready" Then
                                Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
                                For CustCol = 4 To 19 'Move Through 9 Columns
                                    TagName = .Cells(7, CustCol).Value 'Tag Name
                                    TagValue = .Cells(CustRow, CustCol).Value 'Tag Value
                                     With WordDoc.Content.Find
                                        .Text = TagName
                                        .Replacement.Text = TagValue
                                        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                                        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll 'Find & Replace all instances
                                     End With


                                Next CustCol
                                    .Range("d" & CustRow).Value = "Done"
                                       FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("c" & CustRow).Value & "_" & .Range("i" & CustRow).Value & ".docx"
                                       WordDoc.SaveAs FileName
                                .Range("d" & CustRow).Value = "Done"






                                          ' WordDoc.Close
                                    End If
                        Kill (FileName) 'Deletes the PDF or Word that was just created

        Next CustRow
        WordApp.Quit
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So there's a lot here and writing all this from scratch would require quite a bit of coding. Please start by posting the code you've got and state the **specific** problems you have encountered.

Comment: Just want to know the following:
1. vba code to send print command to specific printer
2. a message box when the printer completed the printing.
does that make sense or still needed to view code please.

Comment: My answer below should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

**Choose printer**

```
Application.ActivePrinter = Printers(2) ' set index to correct printer in the printers collection
```

**Print command statement**

```
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

**Message**

```
MsgBox "The sheet was printed."
```

Comment: Thanks for these command. 
I am willing to print the word document by its name or currently opened from excel. so your mentioned command works?

Comment: @ rehanemis Again, if you want more help than just pointers, then please post your code and please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before doing so.

Comment: @rehanemis This code does not compile, even though I added the `Microsoft Word Object Library` under Tools/References, so I assume you made some edits before posting?

Comment: there is other module code too and sheets references, Actually not small lines of code. Anyhow, I will be back to you after to add/modify the code. will share the situation tomorrow. .

Comment: Hi Miqi,
our printer not accepting the input through word document so i planed to mail merge with PDF. I am working on it and 90% it is working. Just more testing it. Hopefully it will work fine.